# Command-line tool for converting PLIST to JSON?

Tags: objective-c, json, plist

Is there a command line tool available for converting .plist files to JSON?

If not, what would be the approach for creating one using Objective-C or C on a Mac? For instance, there is JSONKit, for Objective-C. How would one go about opening a .plist file, pass it to JSONKit, and serialize that as JSON?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

If you are on a Mac you can use the plutil tool on the command line (this comes with the developer tools I believe):

```
plutil -convert json -o Data.json Data.plist
```

If you want to just overwrite the existing file, you can omit the `-o` parameter:

```
plutil -convert json Data.plist
```

Comment: This will overwrite the original plist. To prevent this command from overwriting the original file pass the `-o` flag. ie `plutil -convert json Data.plist -o Data.json`

Comment: One complication with this is that some Plist data types cannot be converted by plutil. The workaround I found was to do some pre-processing on the plist before passing it to plutil. Specific to the plist that I'm working with, I had to replace both `<data>` and `<date>` tags with `<string>`.

Comment: I don't know on what Macs this is supposed to work, but on 10.6 it says: `Unknown format specifier: json`

Comment: Your second command will convert the original plist file all the same. It should be `plutil -convert json  -o Data.json Data.plist`. That's to say, the original plist file should be at last. @ADAM

Comment: use `plutil -convert -r json` to receive the json in a human-readable format

Comment: Pass a hyphen as the output file to print to stdout. `plutil -convert json -o - file.json`

Comment: You need to edit your answer and completely remove the 1st command, which destructively modifies the original plist file. It is simply wrong for this purpose.

Comment: For the life of me, I can't get this command to work, "invalid object in plist for destination format".

Answer (score 5):

The following gets the job done—

```
// convertPlistToJSON.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "JSONKit.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  if(argc != 3) { fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s FILE_PLIST FILE_JSON\n", argv[0]); exit(5); }

  NSString *plistFileNameString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[1]];
  NSString *jsonFileNameString  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[2]];

  NSError *error = NULL;

  NSData *plistFileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:plistFileNameString options:0UL error:&error];
  if(plistFileData == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to read plist file.  Error: %@, info: %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    exit(1);
  }

  id plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:plistFileData options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:NULL error:&error];
  if(plist == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to deserialize property list.  Error: %@, info: %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    exit(1);
  }

  NSData *jsonData = [plist JSONDataWithOptions:JKSerializeOptionPretty error:&error];
  if(jsonData == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to serialize plist to JSON.  Error: %@, info: %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    exit(1);
  }

  if([jsonData writeToFile:jsonFileNameString options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error] == NO) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to write JSON to file.  Error: %@, info: %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    exit(1);
  }

  [pool release]; pool = NULL;
  return(0);
}
```

It does some reasonable error checking, but it's not bullet proof.  Use at your own risk.

You'll need [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) to build the tool.  Place `JSONKit.m` and `JSONKit.h` in the same directory as `convertPlistToJSON.m`, and then compile with:

```
shell% gcc -o convertPlistToJSON convertPlistToJSON.m JSONKit.m -framework Foundation
```

Usage:

```
shell% convertPlistTOJSON
usage: convertPlistToJSON FILE_PLIST FILE_JSON

shell% convertPlistTOJSON input.plist output.json
```

Reads in `input.plist`, and writes the pretty printed JSON to `output.json`.

Answer (score 5):

If you run into issues with "invalid object in plist for destination format", you probably have bytes-like data in the plist, which plutil does not consider serializable to json.

Python has built-in plist support, and we can specify a custom default function to specify what to do when serialization fails (e.g. on bytes). If you don't care about the bytes fields, we can just serialize them as `'<not serializable>'` with the following python one-liner:

`python -c 'import plistlib,sys,json; print(json.dumps(plistlib.loads(sys.stdin.read().encode("utf-8")), default=lambda o:"<not serializable>"))'`

This takes the stdin, parses the plist, then dumps it to json. For example, to get current power information for your Mac, you can run:

`ioreg -rw0 -c AppleSmartBattery -a | python -c 'import plistlib,sys,json; print(json.dumps(plistlib.loads(sys.stdin.read().encode("utf-8")), default=lambda o:"<not serializable>"))'`

and if you wanted to just get the current charging wattage, you could pipe that into `jq '.[0].AdapterDetails.Watts'`

Answer (score 4):

Using mac utils

### Convert plist to json

```
plutil -convert json -o output.json input.plist
```

### Convert json to plist

```
plutil -convert xml1 input.json -o output.plist
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is fairly simple to do this:

```
NSArray* array = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[@"~/input.plist" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]]retain];
SBJsonWriter* writer = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];
NSString* s = [[writer stringWithObject:array] retain];
[s writeToFile:[@"~/output.json" stringByExpandingTildeInPath] atomically:YES];
[array release];
```

I never got around to making it accept arguments as I only needed to do 3 files.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a tool in python to do this. See here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/plist2json

Works from command line on os x or linux distros, batch converts a directory. It's short and simple so it should be easy to modify for your own purposes.

Answer (score 2):

There is a native way, to convert `plist`'s to `json`. It's called [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Here is an example on how to use it, and convert a `plist` file to a `json` file:

```
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"input.plist"];

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:plistDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[jsonString writeToFile:@"output.json" atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Answer (score 2):

Converts `Filename.plist` to `Filename.json`:

```
plutil -convert json -r -e json Filename.plist
```

`-convert` indicates format, `-r` makes the output more human-readable, `-e` specifies an extension

Answer (score 0):

I was annoyed at how kinda complicated converting binary plists to json was, so I created a web, *browser-only* tool that converts binary plist files to json.

your files are not sent anywhere, it's all done in the browser!

https://gregsadetsky.github.io/i-just-want-to-see-the-plist/

its code is open and can be found [here](https://github.com/gregsadetsky/i-just-want-to-see-the-plist).