# Parse plist in Dart

Tags: dart

I am creating a level editor in Dart for my cocos2d-x game and I have to parse animations stored [plist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list) files. Has anyone created or found a library for parsing plists in Dart? If not, I guess I will have to write my own.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any plist parser, but you could convert the plist to JSON (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10991695/1919627) then parse using the dart:convert library:

```
Map parsedData = JSON.decode(mapAsJson);
```

Comment: That is a possible solution but doesn't fully fit my needs. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ElvissStrazdins Did you write it?

Answer (score 0):

Eight years later — a very useful package called [`plist_parser`](https://pub.dev/packages/plist_parser) is available on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/). It is based on the [`xml`](https://pub.dev/packages/xml) package to parse [plist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list) data from strings, files or binaries.